# Casting an object to a generic (or storing inner class variable as generic)

Tags: java, generics, casting, inner-classes

I'm getting a warning when I try to cast to a generic type from an Object.
Since my underlying data structure on my inner Node class is an array, I can't make Node generic since I can't create generic arrays, and thus my `val` parameter has to be an Object.

is there any work around or a better way of doing this? I could just suppress warnings but I'm not sure if that's going to have ramifications I should be concerned about.

I'm also making different trees that implement the MyTreeI and will all have different Node structures (so I can't just make an actual Node class (would that even work? I don't know.. maybe))

Ex code here:

```
public class MyTree<E> implements MyTreeI<E> {
    private Node root;      // root of tree


    private static class Node {
        private Object val;
        private Node[] children = new Node[2];
    }

    public MyTree() {
    }


    @Override
    public E get(String key) {
        Node x = getNode(key); // helper function, assume it returns node in question
        return (E) x.val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you make Node use `E` as the type of `val`, and children a `List<Node>`, instead of an array?

Comment: I can't make E the type of val since I can't reference a non-static type from within a static reference... and as for making it a List - I have a lot of other code that already takes advantage of the fact that it's an array - I could change it all to work with lists instead but I'd be more inclined to just leave it as is and suppress the warning than redo all that code - or is that a bad idea?

Comment: The Node class would have to be generic as well: `private static class Node<E>`, and the root should be of type `Node<E>`, as well as `x`. `getNode()` should return a `Node<E>`, etc. You can of course use an array, but then you'll have type-safety warnings.

Comment: It wouldn't be ideal for me to do it that way since I'm implementing an interface that doesn't call for generic returns; Im creating different trees and not all the Nodes will be formatted the same, so I just want to return an Element not a Node<E>

Comment: oh wait that was dumb, you meant on my helper function. I see - I still rather only do this on last resort since I'd have to modify a decent chunk of code so if there's any way I could do it with an array that would be amazing, but if not I might just go the List route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't make Node generic since I can't create generic arrays

Making `Node` generic doesn't inhibit you from using arrays of `Node`. You can't create `new Node<E>[...]`, true; but you can create `new Node<?>[...]` or `new Node[...]` and cast it to `Node<E>[]`, or just change the type of `children` to `Node<?>[]`. There are many possible ways to do this.

```
public class MyTree<E> implements MyTreeI<E> {
    private Node<E> root;      // root of tree


    private static class Node<E> {
        private E val;
        private Node<E>[] children = (Node<E>[])new Node<?>[2];
    }

    public MyTree() {
    }


    @Override
    public E get(String key) {
        Node<E> x = getNode(key); // helper function, assume it returns node in question
        return x.val;
    }
}
```